# Difference between Array fetch and Prefetch in OCI

Tags: oracle, oracle-call-interface, prefetch

There is a saying that "Prefetch is a new 8i feature whereby the client will automagically array fetch for you -- you don't have to do array fetching anymore, it'll just happen." from https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=prefetch, seems that prefetch is a replacement for array fetch. While in OCCI api (OCI C++ version), it has SetDataBuffer for array fetch and setPrefetchRowCount for prefetch, see https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNCPP/reference027.htm#LNCPP1019. Seems they can be used together. But in my performance test, I did not see the performance improvement by increasing prefetchCount under specific array size (batch size). So what is the difference of array fetch and prefetch, and how to configure prefetchCount to improve performance?

Comment: How many rows of data are you selecting in total and what is your prefetch rowcount (from memory I think the default is 100 within Oracle (OCCI might be different)? Also, how likely is the database/OS/etc. likely to be already caching the data you're selecting?

Comment: I'm loading 1GB of TPC-H data, which is 6990506 rows in total. And I'm trying to use set BatchSize to 10000, and PrefetchCount from 0 to 10000 does not show any difference.

Comment: These are both values for tuning fetches of data, not for loading data into Oracle DB.

Comment: yes. I'm reading data from Oracle DB.

Answer (score 1):

What datatypes? Prefetching is internally disabled by Oracle Database when queries contain LONG or LOB columns.

If you use prefetching & array fetching together, the general recommendation is to have prefetching enabled at execute time (so the roundtrip between the app & the DB for the execute operation also brings back data, thus reducing overall roundtrips) and then swap to array fetching.

For the general purpose ODPI-C library we default to a [prefetch of 2](https://github.com/oracle/odpi/blob/v4.3.0/include/dpi.h#L87) and [array fetch size of 100](https://github.com/oracle/odpi/blob/v4.3.0/include/dpi.h#L84).  For your own application you might find different values work better.  There are factors such as memory allocation & re-allocation costs etc etc. that play a role.

Comment: I still do not quite understand. Increasing array size should be able to reduce the roundtrips as well. Then why do we need prefetching?

Comment: I use standard TPC-H data, which does not contain LONG or LOB columns.